# How to get specific JSON data in UITableView when Button is clicked in iOS(objective c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I have JSON data which looks like this:

```
 {
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
      "playerId": "j_mohammed",
      "playerName": "Jason Mohammed",
      "playerShortName": "Jason Mohammed",
      "PlayingRole": 3,
      "Credit": 85,
      "Player_Points": 45,
      "TeamName": "wi",
      "TeamColor": "1"
    },
    {
      "playerId": "s_gabriel",
      "playerName": "Shannon Gabriel",
      "playerShortName": "ST Gabriel",
      "PlayingRole": 4,
      "Credit": 80,
      "Player_Points": 0,
      "TeamName": "wi",
      "TeamColor": "1"
    },
    {
      "playerId": "s_hope",
      "playerName": "Shai Hope",
      "playerShortName": "S Hope",
      "PlayingRole": 1,
      "Credit": 85,
      "Player_Points": 0,
      "TeamName": "wi",
      "TeamColor": "1"
    },
    {
      "playerId": "e_lewis",
      "playerName": "Evin Lewis",
      "playerShortName": "Evin Lewis",
      "PlayingRole": 3,
      "Credit": 85,
      "Player_Points": 281,
      "TeamName": "wi",
      "TeamColor": "1"
    },
   {
      "playerId": "m_hafeez",
      "playerName": "Mohammad Hafeez",
      "playerShortName": "Mohammad Hafeez",
      "PlayingRole": 2,
      "Credit": 90,
      "Player_Points": 0,
      "TeamName": "pak",
      "TeamColor": "4"
    },
    {
      "playerId": "f_ashraf",
      "playerName": "Fahim Ashraf",
      "playerShortName": "Fahim Ashraf",
      "PlayingRole": 3,
      "Credit": 85,
      "Player_Points": 0,
      "TeamName": "pak",
      "TeamColor": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've already parsed this JSON into my app.
View of my app looks like this:
[image]

As it shows that I've 4 buttons at top of the view:

[image]

I've taken TableView in ViewController where I've parsed data:

[image]

This is what I've done. Now my main question is that I want show only wicket keeper's list from JSON in tableview when I click on button "WK", batsman's list when I click on "BAT", etc. I've done just parsing right now from it's showing all data from JSON and don't know how to show selected data in TableView when button is clicked.

Whether player is bowler, batsman or wicket keeper it is stored as `"PlayingRole"` in JSON. 
So, if player is `Wicket keeper its role is:1
All rounder:2
Batsman:3
Bowler:4`

This is the code I've done:

```
NSString *mainurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.102/redbull11/webservices/api/getMatcheSquad/“];

NSString *playerurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",mainurl,match_id2];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:playerurl];

NSLog(@"mainurl: %@",url);

NSURLSessionConfiguration *csc=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *csession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:csc delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURLSessionDataTask *ctask=[csession dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error){

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

getsuccess = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];               

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

 NSString *success =[getsuccess valueForKey:@"success"];

 if([success boolValue] == YES)

 {   

NSArray *arr =[getsuccess valueForKey:@"data"];

for ( NSDictionary *dic2 in arr) {

NSMutableArray *temp =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"playerShortName"]];

[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"Credit"]];

[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"Player_Points"]];

[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"TeamName"]];

[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"PlayingRole"]];

[getLoc addObject:temp];

}}

 NSLog(@"%@",getLoc);

 [_playerselect reloadData];

[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

 });

});

 }];

[ctask resume];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    selectTeamCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"names" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *arr =[[NSMutableArray  alloc]init];

    arr = [getLoc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);

    cell.playerName.text = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.playerCredit.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:1]stringValue];
    cell.playerPoints.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:2]stringValue];
    cell.teamName.text = [arr objectAtIndex:3];
   return cell;
}
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And... what's your code?

Comment: @Maulik Desai Parse json according to your requirement create two arrays one for batsman and one for keeper append appropriate data.And fetch them accordingly.

Comment: @AlejandroIván see I've edited question.

Comment: where is the wicketkeeper key?

Comment: @DishantRajput in JSON "PlayingRole": 1 indicates wicketkeeper.

Comment: @TusharSharma thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my question here is what I've done in code:

```
@implementation selectTeam{
int flag;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
flag = 1;
NSString *mainurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.102/redbull11/webservices/api/getMatcheSquad/"];
NSString *playerurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",mainurl,match_id2];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:playerurl];
NSLog(@"mainurl: %@",url);
NSURLSessionConfiguration *csc=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *csession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:csc delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURLSessionDataTask *ctask=[csession dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error)
  {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
getsuccess = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
NSString *success =[getsuccess valueForKey:@"success"];
 if([success boolValue] == YES)
 {
NSArray *arr =[getsuccess valueForKey:@"data"];
for ( NSDictionary *dic2 in arr) {
NSMutableArray *temp =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
playerrole = [[dic2 valueForKey:@"PlayingRole"]stringValue];
NSLog(@"role: %@",playerrole);
if ([playerrole isEqual:@"1"]) {
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"playerShortName"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"Credit"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"Player_Points"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"TeamName"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"PlayingRole"]];
[wkeeper addObject:temp];
}
 else if ([playerrole isEqual:@"2"]) {
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"playerShortName"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"Credit"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"Player_Points"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"TeamName"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"PlayingRole"]];
[allrounder addObject:temp];
}
else if ([playerrole isEqual:@"3"])
 { [temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"playerShortName"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"Credit"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"Player_Points"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"TeamName"]];
 [temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"PlayingRole"]];
[batsman addObject:temp];
 }
 else if ([playerrole isEqual:@"4"])
{
 [temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"playerShortName"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"Credit"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"Player_Points"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"TeamName"]];
[temp addObject:[dic2 valueForKey:@"PlayingRole"]];
[bowler addObject:temp];
 }}}
[_playerselect reloadData];
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
});
});
}];
[ctask resume];



- (IBAction)wicketkeeper:(id)sender {
    flag=1;
 _pickplayers.text= @"PICK 1 WICKET-KEEPER";
    [_playerselect reloadData];    
}
- (IBAction)batsman:(id)sender {
    flag=3;
    _pickplayers.text= @"PICK 3-5 BATSMEN";
    [_playerselect reloadData];
}
- (IBAction)allrounder:(id)sender {
    flag=2;
    _pickplayers.text= @"PICK 1-3 ALL-ROUNDERS";
    [_playerselect reloadData];   
}
- (IBAction)bowler:(id)sender {
    flag=4;
    _pickplayers.text= @"PICK 3-5 BOWLERS";
    [_playerselect reloadData];    
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    selectTeamCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"names" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *arr =[[NSMutableArray  alloc]init];
if (flag==1){
        arr = [wkeeper objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    }
    else if (flag==2){
        arr = [allrounder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    }
    else if (flag==3){
        arr = [batsman objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    }
    else{
        arr = [bowler objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}
    cell.playerName.text = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.playerCredit.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:1]stringValue];
    cell.playerPoints.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:2]stringValue];
    cell.teamName.text = [arr objectAtIndex:3];
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve your issue. As a suggestion, you could clean a little bit your code by using new syntax in Objective-C. For example, instead of doing `[someArray objectAtIndex:number]` you could simply do `someArray[number]` with the same effect. That applies to `NSDictionary` too, where you can do `someDictionary[@"key"]` instead of `[someDictionary valueForKey:@"key"]`. Happy coding!

Comment: And to initialize `NSArray`, `NSNumber` and `NSDictionary`, you could use the [literal syntax](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/objective-c-literals-part-1/).

Comment: @AlejandroIván thank you for your suggestion brother!! I've done as u suggested!! thank you for help!!

Answer (score 1):

**If you only want to show wicket keepers.This is only to show wicket keepers in table view cell**

1.) Store your response in an array.

```
NSArray *yourArray =[getsuccess valueForKey:@"data"];//please declare your array globally
```

**then**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return yourArray.count;
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

selectTeamCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"names" forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSDictionary *dictYourDict;
dictYourDict=[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.yourLabel.text=[dictYourDict objectForkEy : @"PlayingRole"];

return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. It is showing wicketkeepers as you said. but I want to change between wkeeper, batsman, bowler and allrounder as I click on different buttons.

Comment: What you could do then is to have another property that indicates which type of data you want to show `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *typeOfData;` and use one info or another in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. The easiest way is to actually have different arrays for each type of selection. The `IBAction` for your button should define that property and call `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: Yes i know mate. I just tell you the way to that . You have to set a variables in each click and call that  in  ibaction. And reload your table view  .

Comment: @AlejandroIván and thanx for help I've done same as you both suggested. and I've solved this problem by mixing your suggestions and some by my coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Use This Predicate to filter Data

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PlayingRole == 1"];
NSArray *arrWicketKeeper = [arrMain filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```